# Validating quality of input text of post

Tags: php, laravel, validation, user-input

I want to check how well blog or post is written. I need validation so that user can not post anything random written like ";sdkjnfwhb fhbdsjkhfb hjsbf shdf"

Is there any strategy that I can use?

Comment: What do you want them to be allowed to post?  Are you just trying to get rid of random characters, or are you trying to bound them to very specific responses?

Comment: I want to make sure that there is nothing random being posted. It is similar to stackoverflow question. If you write that does not make sense it will give you an error saying that your post does not meet quality standard

Answer (score 0):

Something like [PHP Gibberish Detector](https://github.com/buggedcom/Gibberish-Detector-PHP) is what you need. It creates a Markov chain of which letters should and shouldn't appear together and when you apply it to your string it returns a percentage score for the likelihood that the input is nonsense.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that. It looks like what i need